Azure pipeline doesn't wait for function app to complete
I got a function app which can have a very long running operation. I am triggering it with an Azure yaml pipeline like this:
- task: AzureFunction@1
  displayName: Run Dummy function
  inputs:
    function: '$(FunctionURL)/api/DummyFunction'
    key: '$(FunctionKey)'
    method: 'POST'
    body: $(AzureFunctionBody)        
    waitForCompletion: 'true'

Every time I run the pipeline, it fails with an error message:
            > Response Code: 0
            > Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: 
            > Exception Message: The request timed out after 60 seconds as no response was received. (type TimeoutException)

Even though I get an exception in the pipeline, the function app itself is being triggered and fully runs without any issues.
How can I make the pipeline wait for the function app to finish, even if it means waiting for hours?

See my answer below regarding timeouts. For your particular case though it might not be enough to solve your issue.
Take a very good look into the AzureFunction@1 task documentation for more details regarding waitForCompletion property. See sections Remarks and Examples.

OK I read the remarks and understand that a callback must be used in this case. What I didn't understand from the docs - I have no idea what values are needed to be sent to construct the url. What is a plan for a plan url and id? what is a hub? I do see there in the docs an example of default values, but I don't know what should the actual values be or if I can use the exact values of headers as listed in the docs?

@CodeMonkey, Reference the example in the docs of pipeline task "AzureFunction@1", you also need to set callback data that returned to the pipeline task when the request is completed successfully. In the C# example, the value of variable 'successBody' is the callback data. And the method "PostEvent(callbackUrl, successBody, authToken, log);" is returning the data to the pipeline task.

@CodeMonkey, Of course, you also need to set "waitForCompletion: 'true'" on the pipeline task.

@BrightRan-MSFT Can you please also check out this question about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79186820/azure-devops-pipeline-callbacks-and-azure-durable-functions-status-mechanism

@CodeMonkey, I referenced the example shared in the docs, I set up an Azure function app that can returns some data back to the pipeline task. If I set the function to take more than 60s (using a sleep), even if I set "waitForCompletion: 'true'" on the pipeline task, the task still gets filed. If I set the  take less than 60s and not set "waitForCompletion: 'true'", the task can work fine. Not sure, if this is a defect on the pipeline task.

Yes now I understand more about the option to use a callback which is what needed to be done with long running tasks. Thank you for your help. Now I'm also trying to investigate about durable functions in the question I linked in the previous comment.

@CodeMonkey, Looks like the actual behavior on the AzureFunction@1 task is not consistent with that descripted in the docs.

@BrightRan-MSFT It does suppose to wait until a signal back from the callback and not fail immediately like its actually doing..

@BrightRan-MSFT I was told there's some property of a job of a pipeline we need to set in order to get it working? the job should have pool: server
timeoutInMinutes: 14400
I can't test it right now


How can I make the pipeline wait for the function app to finish, even if it means waiting for hours?

You can use the job timeout setting to specify the limit in minutes for running the job - example:
jobs:
- job: Deploy
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  steps:
    # ...

Setting the value to zero means that the job can run:

Forever on self-hosted agents
For 360 minutes (6 hours) on Microsoft-hosted agents with a public project and public repository
For 60 minutes on Microsoft-hosted agents with a private project or private repository (unless additional capacity is paid for)

If the Azure function executes for more than 1 minute, use the Callback completion event. Property waitForCompletion must be set to true. See Example of an Azure Function that uses the callback completion mode.

Didn't work.. all it did was change the exception message abit to:
Exception Message: The operation has timed out (type WebException)

@CodeMonkey check the task's documentation, as I already mentioned.

Can you please also check out this question about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79186820/azure-devops-pipeline-callbacks-and-azure-durable-functions-status-mechanism

@CodeMonkey sorry I can't help you with that - that's something I never did before.

If you edit your answer to include explanation about the callback of waitForCompletion: 'true', I'll accept the answer

@CodeMonkey there isn't much I can add to my answer that you can't find in the documentation of the task. My answer is not complete, so probably it makes no sense to accept it. As you already noticed it, setting the pipeline job or task timeout alone is not enough to solve your problem (even though you might need to eventually configure it).

I'm afraid that you won't be able to change this timeout. Look at a post here in Developer Community

As you observed, we have a hard restriction on agentless tasks to a timeout of 60 seconds. If http request takes more than 60 secs to complete, then you should use async mode which means that ‘WaitForCompletion’ property is set to true.
We will close this ticket since it is as designed. If the solution/workaround does not work, please feel free to let us know and we will reopen the ticket and continue to investigate this issue.


Can you please also check out this question about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79186820/azure-devops-pipeline-callbacks-and-azure-durable-functions-status-mechanism
