Azure DevOps pipeline callbacks and Azure Durable Functions' status mechanism
I have an Azure function app with a very long running operation. My main goal here is to be able to get the status of the current run by an external process polling for a state.
I briefly read about these 2 options that seem like a good fit:

Using the task of AzureFunction@1 - This allows me to construct a url that the process can periodically check.

Convert my current function to be an Azure durable function with the Async HTTP APIs pattern - This also has a built in status update of the running function.


What is the difference in what can be achieved between these 2 methods? I would prefer a method which will also allow me to update some string message as a description for the state (for example: "Step 1 Complete". And after that "Step 1 and Step 2 Complete").

The links in Where should a task signal completion when Callback is chosen as the completion event? might be helpful, e.g. see the sample application.

See also Example of an Azure Function that uses the callback completion mode

Seems like the AzureFunction@1 is not behaving as in the docs. It's supposed to wait for a signal from the callback, and yet it fails immediately

I need to check if I might have not set it up correctly.. Still need to know about the differences between these 2 options of signaling

This long running function, how does it currently report progress?


Using the task of AzureFunction@1 - This allows me to construct a url that the process can periodically check.


You cannot check the status of a function invocation using this task unless it is another azure funcion that is able to report the status. Otherwise you are just starting a new function call.
If you rewrite the function as a durable function you can get the status and the outputs of the activities of the function, see the docs
Another option is to have the function report its status by

logging what stages it has completed yet and query that log periodically
calling another endpoint to report is status
writing the status to a table/blob/whatever when the status changes


Until today it was a function which I was responsible for and just needed to make the job done so the only way I knew it was over was by looking at the logs for a conclusion message and then I notified whoever needed it that the job was done. Now I need to automate it so I need to know at least when its done (a progress is a nice to have but not mandatory)

@CodeMonkey  I see. Well, I hope one of the options in my answer will do. Can't think of many more in your scenario.

Do you know how I can poll the callback url? It seems it doesn't support GET operations. I have also asked another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79199629/get-a-custom-message-from-callback-of-task-azurefunction1-in-pipeline
