Get a custom message from callback of task AzureFunction@1 in pipeline
I'm using the task AzureFunction@1 in an Azure yaml pipeline. According to the documentation, you can use a callback to indicate the task if it should pass or fail. This itself works as expected.
What I want to know is if there's a way to display some custom message in the pipeline with some summary of what happened? For example, if the task is supposed to fail, to also display in the pipeline a message like "Failed because of reasons X,Y,Z"? If not possible, is it maybe at least possible to poll the callback url somehow by C# code from another listening process, and get the message that way?

The AzureFunction@1 task can also be used as a check task in the release pipeline deployment gate: .
So, we can refer the document Send status updates to Azure DevOps from checks which also introduce more usage about Invoke Azure Function task. It mentions:

You can provide status updates to Azure Pipelines users from within your checks using Azure Pipelines REST APIs.
The steps to send status updates are:

Create a task log
Append to the task log
Update timeline record


Based the above information, I tested the Append to the task log API to add more logs to the task.
First, here is the header in JSON format to be attached to the request sent to the function:

We will use the values from the header in the next steps, including the "HubName", "PlanId", "ProjectId","TaskInstanceId" and "AuthToken".
Here is my test PowerShell script
$AuthToken =""
$organization = ""
$projectId = ""

$hubName = "build"
$planId = ""
$logId = 4
$logURI = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$projectId/_apis/distributedtask/hubs/$hubName/plans/$planId/logs/${logId}?api-version=7.1"


$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "bearer " + "$AuthToken"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/octet-stream'
}

$logBody = @(
    '##[error]==================================='
    '##[error]Failed because of reasons X,Y,Z'
    '##[error]==================================='
)

foreach ($line in $logBody) {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $logURI -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body $line
}

The $logId is found from the API https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$projectId/_apis/distributedtask/hubs/$hubName/plans/$planId/logs?api-version=7.1" based on the TaskInstanceId.

Test result:

C# code sample to send the request to Append to the task log API:
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var authToken = "your_auth_token";
        var organization = "your_organization";
        var projectId = "your_projectId";
        var hubName = "build";
        var planId = "your_planId";
        var logId = 4;
        
        var logURI = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectId}/_apis/distributedtask/hubs/{hubName}/plans/{planId}/logs/{logId}?api-version=7.1";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

        var logBody = new[]
        {
            "##[error]===================================",
            "##[error]Failed because of reasons X,Y,Z",
            "##[error]==================================="
        };

        foreach (var line in logBody)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(line, Encoding.UTF8, "application/octet-stream");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(logURI, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Log entry posted successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to post log entry: {response.StatusCode}");
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
}



Before I had a chance reading the docs you mentioned.. Is your answer only relevant to release pipelines or can be used on every pipeline? Also, I didn't understand so much your comment about the log id - Is it something I need to do manually once or each time it runs by code? I expected that your url for the log id will be based on a pipeline run id or something like that.. and what is the task instance id you mentioned? Also, do you might have a C# example of your powershell script, especially the part of choosing if the log message will indicate an error or just a plain mid run status?

Hi, yes it can be used on every pipeline. I shared the screenshot of the release pipeline just to point out that you can find the content about these APIs in the documentation related to using Azure Function tasks in checks. The main point is to let you know that there is such an API named "Append to the task log" can be used.  The TaskInstanceId is also from the header that was attached to the request sent to the function, together with $hubName and $planId.

To get the $logId, you can write some code to call that API in code to get the ID, or you just need to find the id manually once. Because the id will not change when the order of this task does not change in the total tasks.  I have updated the answer with more explanation and the c# example code.

Sorry it took so long. I only now was able to test this. This solution is partially working and maybe you could help me understand why not fully. In my code I get a request to the function, then using the code above to log some stuff to task logs, starting a new thread and returning immediately. Inside the new thread I'm also logging additional stuff. Only the logs inside the new thread are actually working and being logged. It seems like the api call to get the log id returns me only 3 values when requesting before the new thread starts, and 4 including the correct one inside the new thread

I'm not sure if the problem occurs because there should be some delay, or if its because there is still no log exists until the main thread returns with a response before the calls to log are invoked in the new thread?

Hi @CodeMonkey, sorry for the late response. When I tested it, I felt that it was not some kind of delay, but the second one you mentioned.

Is it possible to somehow overcome it? I was also thinking about using it for app functions who don't return immediately, but if its because no log is created then it won't be possible?
